# Convert WMA byte array to WAV in C# (NAudio)

Tags: c#, audio, wav, naudio

I am trying to create a WAV object, from a WMA byte array, I've tried the following code, but the software exits, and in the dump file I found the following exception when I try to create fileReader 
"The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access."

```
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("wmatemp.wma", data);
    WMAFileReader fileReader = new WMAFileReader("wmatemp.wma");
    WaveStream waveStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(fileReader);
    WAV wav = new WAV(AudioMemStream(waveStream).ToArray());
```

I know I should not save the .wma to the HDD, but I don't know how to proceed differently, any help ?

Comment: Neither `WmaStream` nor `WMAFileReader` seem to have a constructor that take a `Stream` or a `byte[]` instead of a file name. So unfortunately it looks like it isn't possible.

Comment: Yes :( that is true, are there any alternatives to NAudio ? 
Also, why do you think that it gives me that exception when trying to read from the file ?

Comment: The exception might by because there is close-to-no break between your `WriteAllBytes` and opening it up again - Windows might think it's still open. Unfortunately I am not aware of any alternative libraries. I have no idea if this would work with native / 3rd party methods but one thing you could try is to "trick" it by working with a [MemoryMappedFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd267552(v=vs.110).aspx). I haven't tried this so I really don't know if this can work, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: I will try that and then I will post my result, thanks !

Comment: I see to be in a pickle, it seems that Visual Studio can't find the namespace to MemoryMappedFile ? I searched in the referenced libraries, it's not there either, even started a new project, still nothing.

Comment: The namesapce `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles` is part of the `System.Core.dll` since .Net 4.0

Comment: My problem is that I am programming in Unity, and it seems Unity is referencing a different library and I don't have access to that class, I tried copying the System.Core.dll into my Unity plugins folder but it does not work. I will a different approach, thank you for you help :D